# User Passwords - Backup

Tags: windows-server-2008

Not sure if this is possible.

I have created some code in order to reset user passwords.
I would like to know if there is any possible way I can create a backup of the current password set in case there is a failure in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Active Directory backup Active Directory. If use local user, then backup SAM and SYSTEM files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still works with Server 2008 but I've always been fond of pwdump. Just be aware that every antivirus program I've ever tried will complain about it.